# Why difference in performance between the TWO queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, performance

I am using SQL Server 2008, and I have two tables

**Table1**

contains 3.5 million records

```
+----+-------------+
| pk | dim1        |
+----+-------------+
indexing applied on column **pk**
```

**Table2**

contains 15 million records

```
+----+-------------+
| fk | fact1       |
+----+-------------+
indexing applied on column **fk**
```

I ran 2 queries on these table to get `t2.fact1`

**Query1**

```
SELECT t2.fact1 
FROM Table1 AS t1, Table2 AS t2 
WHERE t2.fk = t1.pk
```

**Query2**

```
SELECT t2.fact1 
FROM Table1 
WHERE t2.fk IN (SELECT t1.pk FROM Table1 AS t1)
```

The result that got was Query1 took `7 secs` while Query2 took `6 secs`

While some where in blogs I read like if I use `IN` in query like above, will slower the query.

**Question#1:** can anybody suggest why Query2 was faster?

In an another experiment on same table (When NO INDEXING was applied) I ran above queries and again query2 was faster than Query1, unfortunately don't remember its timing.

**Question#2:** can anybody suggest why Query2 was faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

6 vs 7 seconds could easily be measurement errors

- Run both and see the actual execution plan
- Run several times and compare timings
- The 2nd query could run with data in cache, the first one not. Use DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS

Observation: You should use this construct

```
Select t2.fact1 from
    Table1 as t1 JOIN table2 as t2 on t2.fk=t1.pk
```

Edit:

- DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS will clear the data cache
- The JOIN syntax is better and clearer

Of course, now I realise the difference will be caused by query 1 giving different results because of multiplying out rows. That is, you have multiple child rows per parent row. The In won't do this.

I normally go on about this but overlooked it earlier.

What I want to know now is how many rows are returned by each query...

Comment: 1)as am some what new to thing was not able to interpret the execution plan,can please guide me.
2)Ran several times but result was coming something like same.
3)whats this  DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS,please guide,will love to explore these things
4)how will JOIN  affect

but in general Which query should be FASTER?

Comment: will soon in a day or 2 will post the fresh stats again,hope u will reply.